# Is there a way to store the input value when a specific output is reached in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write VBA code in excel for finding the roots of the following equation:

`0 = x (tan(x)) - (0.4186)`

I am first aiming to find a general idea of where the roots are located before using a numerical root finding method.

I have attempted to write code based on the premise that if the product of two  `f(x)` values are negative then a root must lie between them since there has been a change in sign.

My goal is to build a loop function where when `i*(i+1)` is negative and `i<i+1` it stores the root in an array.

I am having difficulty on how to connect the actual outputs of the function to the `i` of the loop and how to store the `x` value at the specific `y` value that meets the condition.

Here is some sample code. I haven't ever needed to write a loop of this form before ... I normally only need to loop through arrays. Any tips to steer me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 0 To i = 100   'just a place holder number for now
For j = 0 To j = 100

i = (j) * Tan(j) - 0.6 * 30 / 43

If (i < 0) Then Exit For  'it will not allow me to add AND If ((i+1)<i)
  
  RootsN = j
  
 Next i
 Next j

End Function
 
 ' debugger says invalid next control variable reference
' I want to store all outgoing roots in an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want but try this. It loops and retians the x and fn(x) values in a 2D array and outputs to Sheet1 those consecutive ones where the sign of f(x) changes.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub calc()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long
    Dim dStart As Double, dEnd As Double, dStep As Double
    Dim ar(), n As Long, x As Double
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ws.Cells.Clear
    ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Step", "x-1", "fn(x-1)", "x", "fn(x)")

    dStart = 1
    dEnd = 10
    dStep = 0.1

    ' determine number of results and make the array big enough
    n = Int(2 + (dEnd - dStart) / dStep)
    ReDim ar(n, 1)
    
    ' calc results
    n = 0: r = 2
    For x = dStart To dEnd Step dStep
       n = n + 1
       ar(n, 0) = x
       ar(n, 1) = fn(x)
       If n > 1 And ar(n, 1) * ar(n - 1, 1) < 0 Then
           ws.Cells(r, 1) = n
           ws.Cells(r, 2) = ar(n - 1, 0)
           ws.Cells(r, 3) = ar(n - 1, 1)
           ws.Cells(r, 4) = ar(n, 0)
           ws.Cells(r, 5) = ar(n, 1)
           r = r + 1
       End If
    Next
    MsgBox n - 1 & " calcs done"

End Sub

Function fn(x)
    fn = x * Tan(x) - (0.6 * 30 / 43)
End Function
```